# Screen glitching to desktop wallpaper when recording

Tags: nvidia, graphics, desktop-recording, obs-studio

I have a problem whenever I'm desktop streaming, or recording, on any software. OBS, discord (screen sharing ) ...etc
the glitch is showing my desktop wallpaper for some reason or just a black color ...

here's a demo 
https://streamable.com/72qfb
https://streamable.com/tm6kh

i have an NVIDIA GT 740m, 2 monitors, 1920x1080 and 1366x768, I'm using the 384 Nvidia drivers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved it by disabling "Allow Flipping" in Nvidia Settings

[image]